# Why is my blazor component with ElementReference and IJSRuntime.InvokeAsync inside for loop not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop

In the markup of a **blazor** (server) component, I'm trying to invoke a javascript function on each element added inside a loop. It's kind of hard to explain...hopefully this code snippet helps:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    ElementReference div;
    <div @ref="div">this should get replaced....</div>
    JS.InvokeVoidAsync("Test", div, i); @* where Test is defined as: function Test(el, i) { el.innerHTML = i; }*@
}
```

If I am going about this the wrong way...what is the right way?

For more context, this is what I'm *actually* trying to do:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@foreach(var data in jsonItems)
{
    ElementReference div;
    <div @ref="div"></div>
    JS.InvokeVoidAsync("JsonView.renderJSON", data, div); @* https://github.com/pgrabovets/json-view *@
}
@code
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> jsonItems = new List<string> {"{}", "{}"};
}
```

I've created this blazor fiddle if that helps... https://blazorfiddle.com/s/428ov3ku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an ElementReference object before it has been assigned a reference to an element. Your component is not yet created and rendered, so no ElementReference object is available. You can only use  ElementReference objects after your component has been rendered.

You can do it like this:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@foreach (var div in divs)
{
  
    <div @ref="div.ElementReference"></div>
  
}
@code
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Div> divs = new List<Div> { new Div{JSON="{1}" },
                                                             new Div{JSON="{2}"},
                                                             new Div{JSON="{3}"}};

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {

        if (firstRender)
        {
            @foreach (var div in divs)
            {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(
               "exampleJsFunctions.jsonRenderer", div.JSON, div.ElementReference);
            
            }
     
        }
    }

    public class Div
    {
        public ElementReference ElementReference { get; set; }
        public string JSON { get; set; } 

    }

 }
```

Put the script at the bottom of your _Host.cshtml file...

```
 <script>
        window.exampleJsFunctions = {
            jsonRenderer: function (json, element) {
                element.innerText = json;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I guess that explains _why_ it's not working. any advice on how to get it to work?

Comment: Nice one, thanks! I actually tried something similar with a dictionary, but using ElementReference as a key didn't work, I guess because it's a struct...

                        `ElementReference tree;
                        <div @ref=tree></div>
                        dict[tree] = v.Value;`